# Which .iso to download to install Android on my home PC?

Tags: android-x86

I checked the Android-x86 downloads list. It contains .iso files for Laptops. I want to install Android on home PC.

Comment: I never understood why people want to run Android on their PCs. Why do you want to?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik its actually quite a useful feature to mess with Android for devving purposes (its x86 vs Google's own AVD which is armv7 emulated and slower)

Comment: @tomm13b I think the 4.0 emulators are native now?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I want to build Android applications using MonoDroid. I think I am more comfortable to work on PC than any other device.

Answer (score 8):

It all depends on the device where you're going to install this Android port.

If you access the [download page of the Android-x86 Project](http://www.android-x86.org/download#JOT_FILECAB_header_Android-x86-4.0-RC1), you'll find a short description for every available ISO to point you out onto the proper download.

Assuming that you're out to try the latest, Android-x86 4.0-RC1 live and installation iso:

- for [AMD Brazos platform](http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.0-RC1-amd_brazos.iso)
- for [ASUS Laptops/Tablets](http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.0-RC1-asus_laptop.iso)   <-- Best bet if your referring to a desktop PC or a Laptop.
- for [ASUS Eee PC family](http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.0-RC1-eeepc.iso)
- for [Lenovo s103t tablet](http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.0-RC1-s103t.iso)
- for [Tegav2 (Atom N455 tablet)](http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.0-RC1-tegav2.iso)

---

For the purpose of completeness,

Here's a small description of the [Android-x86 Project - Run Android on Your PC](http://www.android-x86.org/):

> This is a project to port Android open source project to x86 platform, formerly known as "patch hosting for android x86 support". The original plan is to host different patches for android x86 support from open source community.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you try the latest 4.0 release candidate.

See the release notes and try the closest matching. I was lucky and my unsupported Netbook ran it. YMMV though. It's a question of CPU, GPU, chipset and screen resolution.

http://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-4-0-rc1

It's a live CD so you can just try without installing it first.