# Can Android be installed on the new Win8-Intel Ultrabooks slated to come out late-12 early-13

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which .iso to download to install Android on my home PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25254/which-iso-to-download-to-install-android-on-my-home-pc)
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I am going to buy a new computer in the next 3-4 months and I am thinking about getting a high quality 13.1 inch Windows 8 Ultrabook. I am going to dual boot both Windows8 (for work stuff) and Ubuntu (so I can have something that will actually work). I am looking into getting one of the new touch screen enabled ultra books with folding down displays to form a tablet as well. I was wondering if I could also boot Android 4 or if Android was limited to ARM devices.

Comment: Until the devices are actually released, I don't think that we can do anything but speculate. If you're planning your purchase based on Android alone then you'll probably be best served waiting it out. In the meantime, the two duplicates provide a good collection of information regarding how Android can be installed on non-Android devices (ARM or x86).

Answer (score 1):

## Answering your Question

According to Mike Bell that runs Intel's mobile group:

> **Windows 8 on tablets, Android on smartphones.** Right now, I have as many people working on Windows 8 tablets as I have on Android phones. If someone came to us with a compelling business case for x86 Windows Phone 8, we’d go work with Microsoft. But the way for us to succeed is to focus — through close collaboration with Google on Android, and Microsoft on Windows 8.

Read the entire interview at:

- [ExtremeTech - Intel dismisses ‘x86 tax’, sees no future for ARM or any of its competitors](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/130552-intel-dismisses-x86-tax-sees-no-future-for-arm-or-any-of-its-competitors)

Simply put, you can have Android on the yet to come Cove Point, but it will have a poor performance compared to Windows 8. *(see why bellow)*

---

## Elaborating this

Intel performed tests with the Android operating System, and concluded that it has a poor implementation of threading technology. According to Bell, Android's thread scheduler simply isn't ready for multicore processors.

> Bell told The Inquirer that even the latest version of Android, 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) suffers from problems with threading scheduling that limits the benefits dual core ARM processors bring to Android phones. Intel uses a competing technology, Atom, in its mobile processor.

Read the entire article at:

- [PCWord - Dual Core Processors Wasted on Android, Intel Claims](http://www.pcworld.com/article/257307/dual_core_processors_wasted_on_android_intel_claims.html)

---

## Supporting Mike Bell's Claim

1. **Smartphones**

   Intel powered smartphones available in the market are running Android:

   - [San Diego from Orange](http://shop.orange.co.uk/mobile-phones/orange-recommends-intel/) (available in UK and France)
   - [Lenovo K800](http://appserver.lenovo.com.cn/Lenovo_Mobile_Detail.aspx?gdsid=A2500017128) (available in china)
   - [Xolo X900](http://www.xolo.in/) (available in India)

   One can keep track of this from at [Smartphones with Intel Inside](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/smartphones/power-of-intel-inside.html) webpage.

   Quoting from the Intel page:

   > **A powerful phone meets a powerful OS**
   >
   > Smartphones with Intel Inside® run on the Android OS, giving you access to hundreds of thousands of apps available to download in the Android Market.
2. **Tablets**

   Microsoft launched the Windows 8 Consumer preview, and Intel decided to show off their new Cove Point with it at IDF 2012 in Beijing:

   - [Intel Shows Off Ultrabook-Tablet Hybrid Running Windows 8](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/04/intel-cove-point-ultrabook-tablet-hybrid-running-windows-8/)

   There's no confirmed Intel Cove Point price or release date. What's confirmed is that it will reach the market with Windows 8 already installed natively on the system, thanks to the special x86 architecture used.

---

## Related reading

- [CNET News - Meet the Intel man who's out to beat ARM in smartphones](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30677_3-57455864-244/meet-the-intel-man-whos-out-to-beat-arm-in-smartphones/)

  > Mike Bell runs Intel's mobile group and he's convinced that Intel's Atom chips are better for Android than ARM's ubiquitous processors.

Comment: Claims by Intel that Android doesn't play nice with multi-core ARM processors seem like they should be taken with a **massive** grain of salt, as they are attempting to compete directly with ARM. Do you have any links to sources that corroborate this claim? Has Intel published any research or studies? Have they explained why Android OEMs continue to use multi-core processors in spite of this?

Comment: @eldarerathis At the top part of my answer: *"Simply put, you can have Android on the yet to come Cove Point, but it will have a poor performance compared to Windows 8."*.

Comment: @eldarerathis I too believe that may have been words of war, but a [simple Google search](https://www.google.pt/search?q=intel+mike+bell+position+regarding+android+OS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) shows this claim everywhere.

Comment: @eldarerathis About the extensive answer, since we're talking about a device yet to come, with a still rather unclear future, I've opted to provide some clarification on what the GM of Intel's Mobile division is saying, as to clarify future readers that Intel does use Android, but on matters regarding tablets, they are looking towards Win8.

Comment: @eldarerathis This answer answers the question and provides useful reading material (information supported by links). If you believe that this answer isn't useful to this question, please let me know, I'll remove or improve it.

Comment: I don't get the "Supporting Mike Bell's Claim" section. What is it exactly that supports it?

Comment: I think my question was kind of the same as @RichardBorcsik's. I can see that you stated that you should be able to run Android with "poor performance", but I don't really see information that supports that theory (other than claims from Intel). I'm simply curious if there is any data from another party or if this is basically all statements from Intel interviews. The search you linked to in your comment has a lot of hits, but it all appears to just be articles referencing the one Intel interview (amended my previous comment to make this more obvious).

Comment: @eldarerathis I did read on Intel's website some vague information regarding their interaction with Android on this subject, but no hard statements like "This will not work". I'm basing the "poor performance" assessment by the interview yes. should I rephrase the answer due to the lack of concrete support for this assessment, or even delete it?

Comment: I think you can really do whatever you want with the answer. Whether or not people find it convincing is what the voting system is for, after all, but I wouldn't consider it a "bad" answer. That's basically the only reason I was curious to know if there are other data points - I'm a little skeptical of Intel's claims. You're certainly not obligated to provide such data, but I thought I would ask if you knew of any since it was related.